# regex - Removing text from around numbers in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large subset of data that looks like this:

```
MyApp.Whatever\app.config(115): More stuff here, but possibly with numbers or parenthesis...
```

I'd like to create a replace filter using Notepad++ that would identify and replace the line number "(115):" and replace it with a tab character followed by the same number.

I've been trying filters such as `(\(\d+\):)` and `(\(\[0-9]+\):)`, but they keep returning the entire value in the `\1` output.

How would I create a filter using Notepad++ that would successfully replace `(115):` with tab character + `115`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a quantifier.. `(\(\d+?\):)` where the ? will prevent it from being greedy. Also, since everything is in a () it will group it all and treat it as \1 ..

If it was in perl I'd say `\((\d+?)\):` which should match only the inner part.

Edit:

Just talked with my colleague - he said `s/\((\d+)\)/\t\1/` and if you needed app config in front you could just put that in the front.

Comment: `\d+` or `\d+?` makes no difference.

Comment: Yeah realized that after.. looking at regexes for too long can cripple the mind

Comment: I can understand. :) btw, my comment is not complete, there is no diff between the two regex **in this question**. of course they are different. :)

Comment: @Rethic perl is one of the most useful languages I've ever used.. EVERY programmer should learn perl.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for your needs

replace

```
\((\d+)\):
```

with

```
\t$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `(\(\d+\):)` with `\t\1` will keep the parenthesis and the colon since you've included them in the group (the outer parenthesis), and I think that's what you mean by "they keep returning the entire value."

Instead of escaping those inner parenthesis, escape the outer ones like the other answers have suggested:  `\((\d+)\):` - this says to match a left paren, then match and capture a group of digits, then match a right paren and a colon.  Replacing that with `\t\1` will get rid of the parens and colon that were not in the captured group.